# Find most recent date for ID with multiple records in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a field, "ID", and it has repeat values. (In the example; A21, B42, and C14). My two other fields in the table are "Date" and "Measurement". I want to create a query that will call the previous date WITH matching ID and display the results of that previous row. My end goal is to have a field in my query that will find the change between the current measurement for the ID and the measurement from the date prior.

I have attached an image of the table I have and what I want the query to display.

[image: table and desired query]

Comment: If your database is MS Access then why have you tagged SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to make the described query function:

```
SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement
FROM Table1 AS t LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev ON (tprev.Date_ < t.Date_) AND (tprev.id = t.id)
WHERE not exists 
        (select 1
        from Table1 AS t1
        where 
            t1.ID = t.ID
            and t1.Date_ < t.Date_
            and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly MS Access does not support `lag()`. This however can be emulated with a self-join and a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.id,
    tprev.date as previous_date,
    tprev.measureement as previous_measurement
from Table1 as t
left join Table1 as tprev
    on (tprev.id = t.id)
    and (tprev.dat < t.date)
    and (not exists (
        select 1
        from Table1 as t1
        where 
            t1 = t.id
            and t1.dat < t.date
            and t1.dat > tprev.date
    ))
```

Comment: Hello Dale, thank you. I tried to run this and I am getting the error that the join function is not supported. I am using Access 2007- 2016 file format. Do I need 2019?

Comment: @carmelle: I added parentheses around the `join` conditions, since ms-access is notably picky about this. Is it working better? If not, please provide the full error message.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you. The new error message I am receiving is "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tprev.date previous_date'. My table is access is named "Table1", I guess I should have been more clear on that.

Comment: @carmelle: I edited the query again to add the `as` keyword when defining column and table aliases. I also changed the name of the table to `Table1`.

Comment: Thank you. That edit fixed the error. I am getting another error however, "Syntax error in query expression". It highlights the "and" before "not exists" when I click okay.

Comment: to follow up, I think the issue might have been that the "and (not exists...)" should have been "where not exists". This correction clears the errors. However, when running the query it is requesting I enter the following parameter values; t1, t1.dat, t.date, tprev.Date and tprev.measurement. How can I make it so the query does not require any parameter values to be entered?

Comment: Incase it helps to display how the code you provided has been edited:select 
    t.id,
    tprev.date as previous_date,
    tprev.measureement as previous_measurement
from [Table1] as t
left join Table1 as tprev
    on (tprev.id = t.id)
    and (tprev.dat < t.date) 
    WHERE not exists 
        (select 1
        from [Table1] as t1
        where 
            t1 = t.id
            and t1.dat < t.date
            and t1.dat > tprev.date)

Comment: Here is an update on the query. Right now it is pulling the previous value but each entry is performing that for EVERY station ID above that. I only want the query to pull the value for the previous record, not all previous records. t1 in the "WHERE not exists" is not being recognized as an alias, it is telling me to enter parameter value when I try run the query